# Store name and value of a Button in a mysql table row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, post

I've been hanging on this problem for 3 days and just can't solve it. It seems relatively simple, but unfortunately, I can't do it, because I'm a noob.

I would like to use the button's onclick function to get its 2 pieces of information

````
```html
<input id="'.$row['id'].'" type="button" value="Pause" name="'.$row['name'].'" onclick="pushDataToDB()">```
````

1. name = "'. $ row [' name '].'" [the name reference from a database
   table]
2. and value="Pause"

this two informations i would like to store in some other database table.
I have tried to solve this problem in different ways.

I have tried to store in different ways the event.target.name & event.target.event javascript output in PHP Variables and then use it in the mysql insert line but i failed.

I have tried to post the value to the ajax.php then store the value in a PHP variable and use this as Value to push it to the database, but this also doesn't work

index.php

```php
    <div class="button2">
     <form action="ajax.php" method="POST">
     <input id="'.$row['id'].'" type="button" value="Pause" name="'.$row['name'].'" onclick="pushDataToDB()">
    </Form>
    </div>'
```

script.js:

```js
    function pushDataToDB() {
                $.get("ajax.php"); 
                return false; 
    }
```

ajax.php

```php
    <?php 
    
    include_once ('dbh.php');
    
    
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $sqlAufPause = "INSERT INTO aktuellaufpause (name, pausenart) VALUES ('$name', 'BP')";
        
    }
    
    
    if ($conn->query($sqlAufPause) === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    
    
    
    ?>
```

I would say this is the reason, why the name Value is empty,
but i don't know how to fix ist..

[emptyNameValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZlQC.png)

Comment: It seems that you use 'get' for javascript, and process 'post' for php code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery + AJAX to perform asynchronous POST

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
print_r($row);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="button2">
        <form id="frm">
            <input id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" type="button" value="Pause" name="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" onclick="pushDataToDB()">
        </Form>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pushDataToDB() {
        var name = "<?php echo $row['name'] ?>"; 
        var value = "Pause";
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "name": name,
                "value": value
            },
            success: function(e) {
                if (e == "1") {
                    alert("Success!");
                } else {
                    alert("error!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable(name, value) values('$name','$value')";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if ($result) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "Error!";
}
```

EDITTTT****

I changed

```
var name = "<?php echo $row['id'] ?>";
```

to

```
var name = "<?php echo $row['name'] ?>";
```

since it is the "name" you want stored in the database

Comment: it doesn't work, i think its because i Echo the Button out by each value in the db.
I have no idea how to change this code.
`
 <?php
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $_SESSION['klapptdasFrage'] = $row['name'];

     echo "<td>";
     echo '<div class="button2">
      <form id="frm">
     <input id="'.$row['id'].'" type="button" value="Mittagspause" name="<?php echo '.$row['name'].' ?>" onclick="pushDataToDB()">
     </form>
     </div>'; 
     echo "</td>";

   } else {
    echo "there are no comments";

   }?>`

Comment: Can you please tell me the console log?

Comment: the console log is below

Comment: please edit this with quotes -->  var name = "<?php echo $row['name'] ?>";

Comment: Now i run in the pushDataToDB() success:function error.
there is no consol log error.
The Creation of new DB-Row works, but without the name.
The Name fled is empty, in the value field is Pause

Comment: That's bad. You shouldn't `print_r()` before HTML starts

Comment: I have put new Image in to my question --> [emptyNameValue]
I would think this is the reason.

Comment: nice work in using event.target.name, event.target.value

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem this way.
Thank you so much!!!

index.php

```php
 <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `DB-TABLENAME` ORDER BY `VALUE1`, `VALUE2`";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo '<input style="margin: 0 auto 6px 17px;" type="checkbox" id="scales" name="scales">';
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $row['VALUE1'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $row['VALUE2'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo '<div class="button1">
                    <input id="'.$row['id'].'" type="button" value="BP" name="'.$row['VALUE2'].'" onclick="pushDataToDB()">
                    </div>';    
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo '<div class="button2">
                     <form id="frm">
                    <input id="'.$row['id'].'" type="button" value="Mittagspause" name="'.$row['name'].'" onclick="pushDataToDB()">
                    </form>
                    </div>';    
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    }
            } else {
                echo "there are no comments";
                

            }?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function pushDataToDB() {
        var name = event.target.name; 
        var value = event.target.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "name": name,
                "value": value
            },
             success: function(e) {
                 if (e == "1") {
                     alert("Success!");
                 } else {
                     alert("error!");
                 }
             }
        });
    }
</script>
```

ajax.php

```php
<?php 

include_once('dbconnectioncredentials.php');

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$name = $_POST['VALUE1'];
$value = $_POST['VALUE2'];
$query = "INSERT INTO aktuellaufpause (VALUE1, VALUE2) VALUES ('$name','$value')";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

 if ($result) {
     echo "1";
 } else {
    echo "Error!";
}

?>
```